# Why setting data object in DOMContentLoaded is not persisted in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, babeljs, dom-events

We are facing a strange behaviour while setting data settings object on a form node inside a DOMContenLoaded event handler, I've created a simple jsfiddle to describe the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/804q13g2/

Ad you can see, I've setup three different data properties on the `form#me`, one inline, one inside DOMContentLoadad and one inside jQuery document ready event handler; when you press the button, the data setting will be pasted on screen and you can see that the second data property `"ciao":"mondo"` is missing.

Can you help me to understand why this is happening?

Anyway I've seen that disabling BabelJS/ES5 inside the snipped here on Stack Overflow it's working as intended!

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  $("#me").data("ciao", "mondo");
})
$(function() {
  $("#me").data("ciao2", "mondo2");
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var a = $(document.createElement("p")).text(JSON.stringify($("#me").data()));
    $("#banner-message").append(a);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="me" data-test="passed">
  <div id="banner-message">
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <button type="button" id="btn">Change color</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The code is run as an event handler already. Unlike `$(function () {..})`, the native `DOMContentLoaded` event doesn't fire if it is set after the DOM has been loaded. See your code working at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xj976ycd/) when the code is placed in the head section.

Comment: The problem is because your fiddle isn't correctly configured. You've set the JS to run 'on load'. `DOMContentLoaded` has already fired by this point, so your first event never fires to set `ciao`. To fix this set the load type to `No wrap - in head` (or `in body`) then it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ojz7bnpL/

Answer (score 1):

Your script is probably only getting a chance to run *after* `DOMContentLoaded` was fired. If you want to play it safe, you should cover both possibilites:

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  // DOMContentLoaded already fired, no need to wait for it
  doStuff();
} else {
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doStuff);
}
```

If `document.readyState` is `complete`, it means DOMContentLoaded already fired (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) for all document states).

And that's why it doesn't work in jsfiddle either. To make it work, you need to set your script to run before the event fires, like this:

[image: jsfiddle]

The correct order of events is:

- document.readyState changes to `interactive`
- window's `DOMContentLoaded` gets fired
- document.readyState changes to `complete`
- window's `load` gets fired

If you want to verify this order yourself, [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luciopaiva/grs82byv/19/).